# MySQLi prepare statement returning false

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to delete a line from my database table and my msqli prepared statement is returning false. I've error checked the $commentId and it is being passed through correctly. But I cannot find the reason  the it is not working.

Please Help!

```
<?php
session_start();

include('connect.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true && $_SESSION['id'] == 43) {
    DeleteRowFunction($_POST['commentId']);
} else {
    echo "You are not authorized to delete comments";
}

function DeleteRowFunction($commentId) {
    //$deleteComment = "DELETE FROM `login`.`commenttable` WHERE `commenttable`.`id` = ?";
    $deleteComment = "DELETE FROM commenttable WHERE id = ?";
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $deleteComment)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $commentId);        
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What does your database table look like?

Comment: Don't just echo `error`, use `echo mysqli_error($connection)` and you'll see the reason.

Comment: Where do you set the variable `$connection`?

Comment: @Barmar I'm guessing its inside the `include('connect.php');` line. OP, can we take a gander at your connect.php?

Comment: You've a scope issue.

Comment: Thanks guys you were all on the right path. I needed to set $connection as a global variable and pass it through the function because it had no idea where that variable was. Stupid me over looked it again and again. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting the `$connection` variable in your function. If you had error reporting enabled, you would have seen a warning about the undefined variable being used.

I assume it's being set in `connect.php`, but global variables are not visible inside functions. You either have to pass it as an argument to the function:

```
DeleteRowFunction($connect, $_POST['commentId']);
...
function DeleteRowFunction($connection, $commentId) {
    ...
}
```

or you need to put `global $connection;` at the beginning of `DeleteRowFunction()`.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I spent hours on this and you were right. $connection is within connect.php and I needed to set the variable inside of the function. Should have been more obvious but I kept over looking it :-)

Comment: I hope you've now learned your lesson not to disable warnings. "Notice: undefined variable $connection" should have made it very obvious.